# IF... ELSE in WHERE clause MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to use a IF...ELSE function in a MySQL WHERE statement without success.

I have this query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM mytable 
WHERE restrcountry NOT LIKE '%*nl*%' 
  AND (IF languages LIKE '%*nl*%', 1, 0) = 1;
```

Ok, this is my query with IF statement.

However, how can I use also "ELSE"?

Example, I would like to do something similar:

IF language match *nl* ---> select id field where language is *nl*

ELSE IF language NOT match *nl* ---> select id field where language is *en*

How can I do this in a MySQL query, please?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Could you post some sample data, and the intended results of your query?

Comment: what is `select id field where language is nl`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The syntax for `IF` is :

```
 IF(test_expr, then_expr, else_expr)
```

so you could do something like `IF(test1, result1, IF(test2, result2, else_result))` but it would not be very readable, so there's the `CASE` expression for that purpose.

```
CASE WHEN  test1 THEN result1
WHEN test2 THEN result2
ELSE else_result END
```

If you want to condition a select column, you can use the `IF` in the select fields directly:

```
SELECT IF(match, nl_column en_column) AS lang 
FROM table
```

Note that an expression in a where clause is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, so writing

```
IF(expr, TRUE, FALSE)
```

is the same as

```
expr
```

Answer (score 8):

use CASE instead

```
CASE
    WHEN languages LIKE '%*nl*%' THEN 1 
    WHEN languages NOT LIKE '%*nl*%' THEN 0
 END as languages
```