# mysql query with if and else statement

Tags: php, mysql

I need mysql query that will :

```
IF (result=win){SELECT dobitak} else if (result=half_win) {SELECT dobitak/2} else if (half_lost) {SELECT stake/2} else{0};
FROM matches 
WHERE id=$id
```

but i dont know whats the best solution to write query like this.

Comment: is `dobitak/2` a table name? i don't understand that part

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683185/if-else-in-where-clause-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select case when result ='win' then dobitak
            when result = 'half_win' then dobitak/2
            when result = 'half_lost' then stake/2
            else 0
       end as result
FROM matches 
WHERE id=$id
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do what you want with a `case` statement:

```
select (case when result = win then dobitak
             when result = half_win then dobitak/2
             when half_lost then stake / 2
             else 0
        end)
from matches
where id = $id;
```